# Running airflow tasks in parallel dynamically

Tags: python, airflow

I have a DAG that takes input from XCOMS.
The input is a list of tuples.
the list length could change at each run.
I want my dag to run a KubernetesPodOperator with each tuples as argument.
What i do not know is how to make a loop over the list and each time running only one  KubernetesPodOperator (with one of the tuples) and if there is a possibility to run parralely let say 3 KubernetesPodOperator at the same time each one with a different tuples.

This list could be very long and i cannot run more than three pods in parallel dur to the ressources that i have

Comment: Interesting -- You might be able to use [dynamic task mapping](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/authoring-and-scheduling/dynamic-task-mapping.html#mapping-with-non-taskflow-operators), but I'm not sure if it'll work with KubernetesPodOperator (KPO). Try dynamic task mapping combined with [task instance limits](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/authoring-and-scheduling/dynamic-task-mapping.html#placing-limits-on-mapped-tasks). If this doesn't work with KPO, can you use the KubernetesExecutor?

Comment: i was not able to fo it with dynamic task mapping.
about KubernetesExecutor i do not iunderstand how it;s differ from KPO.
KPO open a pod  each call.This is not like KubernetesExecutor ?

Comment: _This is not like KubernetesExecutor?_ No. The Executor is what distributes the jobs and manages the tasks/jobs/pods ([link](https://medium.com/international-school-of-ai-data-science/executors-in-apache-airflow-148fadee4992)). Whereas you may look at the pods as the jobs themselves. You may be using a Celery executor.  Also: If `dynamic task mapping` doesn't work... Have you considered creating a full DAG with your parallelizable task in it and trigger it passing each tuple as an argument? (via a TriggerDagRunOperator) ? It's a bit annoying since you'd have 2 DAGs, but it may be a workaround.